# Randomize links in multiple divs

Tags: jquery, html

I'm not very familiar with jQuery but I have been trying to use this script to randomize (on page load) all `a` links within multiple `div`s each with `class="category"`. Each `a` link has a class of "fancybox-img" and contains an `img` within the tag - I would like each respective `img` to remain within its original `a` after randomization

JS BIN:

http://jsbin.com/yupizuqubu/1/edit

HTML:

```
            <div class="category">
            <h4>PIZZA CATS</h4>
                <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="gallery-1" href="img/art/painting/bag-man.jpg"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/419613535971184640/FEzxylpk_400x400.jpeg"  class="img-responsive" height="50"></a>
                <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="gallery-1" href="img/art/painting/shnozzle.jpg"><img src="http://www.spindletoprollergirls.com/webdesign/KCruse/Images/Cats%20in%20Space/PizzaKittenLG.jpg"  class="img-responsive" height="50"></a>
                <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="gallery-1" href="img/art/painting/bag-man.jpg"><img src="http://cdn.acidcow.com/pics/20120124/cats_on_pizza_boxes_20.jpg"  class="img-responsive" height="50"></a>
                <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="gallery-1" href="img/art/painting/bag-man.jpg"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/OuUe8Da.jpg"  class="img-responsive" height="50"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="category">
                <h4>BREAD CATS</h4>
                <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="gallery-1" href="img/art/painting/bag-man.jpg"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Bmlk3bJIMAE1jlR.jpg:large"  class="img-responsive" height="50"></a>
                <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="gallery-1" href="img/art/painting/shnozzle.jpg"><img src="http://www.mancertified.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Cats-bread-slices25.jpg"  class="img-responsive" height="50"></a>
                <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="gallery-1" href="img/art/painting/bag-man.jpg"><img src="http://letssmiletoday.com/uploads/images/9460-bread-cat.jpg"  class="img-responsive" height="50"></a>
                <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="gallery-1" href="img/art/painting/bag-man.jpg"><img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/g8du14oxTM8/hqdefault.jpg"  class="img-responsive" height="50"></a>
            </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
$('.category').randomize('a');
    $.fn.randomize = function(selector){
        var $elems = selector ? $(this).find(selector) : $(this).children(),
            $parents = $elems.parent();
        $parents.each(function(){
            $(this).children(selector).sort(function(){
                return Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5;
            }).detach().appendTo(this);
        });
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the placement of the selector `$('.category').randomize('a');`

Here's the correct jQuery code:

```
    $.fn.randomize = function(selector){
        (selector ? this.find(selector) : this).parent().each(function(){
            $(this).children(selector).sort(function(){
                return Math.random() - 0.4;
            }).detach().appendTo(this);
        });

        return this;
    };
    $('.category').randomize('a');
```